# NSPredicate of NSArray in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate, predicate

My Array

```
(
   {id:1,data:(@"macbook",@"mac mini")},
   {id:2,data:(@"ipad",@"ipod")},
   {id:3,data:(@"macbook",@"ipod")}
)
```

I have a predicate

```
NSString *text = @"mac";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(data contains[cd] %@)",text];
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but it doesn't loop over my array inside my dictionary
(my result should be an array containing 2 objects with id 1 and 3)

Comment: Could you show us how you're initializing your array? are you sure you have what you think in the `array` variable?

Comment: You can do this, but it's going to be tricky. Dave DeLong gave the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4831366/312312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString* text = @"mac" ;
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any data contains[cd] %@",text] ;
NSArray* filteredArray = [theArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally find `NSPredicate` formats very error prone.

You may consider using a block in order to filter your `NSArray`

```
NSString * filterString = @"mac";
NSIndexSet * indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray * entry = obj[@"data"];
    for (NSString * value in entry)
        if ([value rangeOfString:filterString].location != NSNotFound)
            return YES;
    return NO;
}];
NSArray * filteredArray = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

It's definitely longer and more verbose, but I find it definitely easier to read and debug.